# Exclude data from being captured by loop-back mode in WASAPI

Tags: windows, audio, wasapi

Is it possible to exclude audio data from being captured by the `IAudioClient` loop-back mode (`AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK`) or to render a audio stream that will not be contained in the loop-back captured audio data.

A stream in exclusive mode (`AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE`) is not captured but it   also prevents other applications from rendering audio data on the same device.

Answer (score 3):

A client can enable loopback mode only for a shared-mode stream (AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED). Exclusive-mode streams cannot operate in loopback mode.

Comment: so basically exclusive-mode streams won't show up in the loopback capture?

Comment: Yes, I think the reason being that in the exclusive mode only your app have access to the audio endpoint which MAY cause other applications that need access to that device to stop functioning. This is just my answer...